# Difference between OWIN/Katana and Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, owin, katana

I bumped into OWIN and Katana and I am now trying to understand what this is really about. From what I understand is that it simply tries to separate the web application from the web host.

So it basically says that when you build an ASP.NET MVC web application that your tied to IIS when you deploy the web application. With OWIN/Katana you don't have that problem. That's what I understand from it, is this correct?

If so, then why would I want to use OWIN/Katana in my project when I could simply use "mod_mono" to deploy my ASP.NET web application to a server like NGINX, Apache etc.

Because that's basically the goal of the OWIN project right? But I find it more trouble to implement OWIN/Katana into my web application then to just simply use the *Web API* of MVC and later on deploy it to a Mono environment. I could even run it in Linux if i want.

So when should one choose OWIN/Katana over Mod Mono? Does it really makes a difference in the end?

Comment: IMO too broad for SO...

Comment: Well, OWIN\Katana doesn't work with Asp.Net WebForms and MVC

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov With the goal to be able to host it on different Web servers right? So why would I want that if could simply use ASP.NET (the way i'm used to it) and use Mono instead to host it on a different Web Server?

Comment: OWIN is all about components and separation. So, in theory it easier to integrate own components into OWIN and it's easier to unit tests them. Another advantage that you mention - SelfHosted application. Yes, you can use it to host Web API in console application for example, but it won't have advantages that Apache, IIS have for configuration, rules, etc.